# Javascript change event not firing in cucumber test

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber

I have two text fields, date and time which have a class 'date-time-field', and a hidden field datetime.  I am trying to use javascript to combine the two whenever either date or time is changed, and store that in the datetime hidden field.  Here is the javascript (converted from coffeescript):

```
$('.date-time-field').change(function() {
  var date, time;
  date = $('#date').val();
  time = $('#time').val();
  return $('#start_time').val(date + " " + time);
});
```

My cucumber test has the @javascript tag so that it will run in the Firefox window.  It passes as long as I keep the focus on the Firefox window that the test opens, however if I move the focus to another window I have open it fails as the change event doesn't fire. I'm worried that this will reproduce in production if a user does something weird.

The step definition is filling in a form:

```
When /^I create a valid event$/ do
  fill_in :name, :with => "Blackbeard's modest event for modest folk"
  select Tier.first.number.to_s, :from => 'event_tier_id'
  select Venue.first.name, :from => 'event_venue_id'
  fill_in 'date', :with => "05/03/2012"
  fill_in 'time', :with => " 08:45"
  click_button 'Save'      
end
```

Should I be using another event like blur, maybe in addition to change, or is it a non-issue for production and I should just put a wait_for call in my test?

Comment: If you're using Windows, then FirefoxDriver has turned on `native_events`. WebDrivre requires Firefox window to be focused to work properly with such events, so it looks more like a WebDriver "feature" rather than your code problem.

Comment: Using mac, is that relevant still?

Comment: Hm... OS X completely lacks NativeEvents support on Firefox. Can you show what you do with Selenium?

Comment: I added the step definition if thats what you meant by "what you do with Selenium"...

Comment: Thanks, it's straightforward. So, if you were using WebDriver with enabled `NativeEvents`, I'd say that this is not your problem, because WebDriver requires browser window to be focused. However, as long as you're using OS X, I'm not sure because there is no `NativeEvents` implementation for Firefox there.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/620), capybara's `fill_in` does not actually trigger a `change` event when a textarea loses focus.  jQuery, on the other hand, defers the `change` event on the textarea *until* the element loses focus (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)).

So what I'm guessing is that when you move the focus to another window, `fill_in` does not trigger the `change` event as it should, and since the focus is lost the `change` event is never triggered thereafter either.

When the focus is *not* lost, however, the save button is clicked while the window is still in focus, and (I'm guessing) that this *does* successfully trigger the change, setting the hidden `datetime` field.

This is just a conjecture based on a few tidbits of information. In terms of a solution, a few ideas were posted in the github discussion above, I'd suggest having a look at those.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for `:selenium` to trigger `blur/change` without needing a jquery or javascript execution:

```
field.send_keys :tab
```